# How to get control used in template in user control code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How could I get a DataGrid control used in xaml style template to use it in code?

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw">

                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder">

                                    <DataGrid x:Name="PART_PopupDataGrid" />

                                </Border>
                            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                        </Popup>
                        <ToggleButton Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="false"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboGrid" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridComboBoxStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There is how I tried to get DataGrid control in user control, but not successfully:

```
var v1 = this.FindName("PART_PopupDataGrid");
var v2 = this.Template.FindName("PART_PopupDataGrid", this);
var v3 = ComboGrid.FindName("PART_PopupDataGrid");
```

How could I get this control in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common requirement. In fact, it's so common that Microsoft even have a page on MSDN specifically for this:

> [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613586(v=vs.100).aspx)

Basically, if you have a reference to *the `ComboBox` that the `ControlTemplate` is applied to* (let's call it `ComboBox`), then you should be able to do this:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = 
    ComboBox.Template.FindName("PART_PopupDataGrid", ComboBox) as DataGrid;
```

Comment: MSDN Link no longer available. New Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb613586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you @ecreif, but your link is for a non-English page on MSDN. I have found another link to replace the broken one with.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I usually choose 'original' rather than 'translated', because most msdn articles have a very bad auto translation. So for me it looked like a standard english article. Anyway, thanks for updating.